# get associated data using get request using cake3 php for search form result

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

If i'm working on search form using cake 3 , and i have get the results according to the inserted Id to url  using this line

```
$data = $this->CustodyKeys->HoldersKeys->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('HoldersKeys.id'=> $this->request->query['holders_keys_id'])));
```

Now , i need to get related data which is associated to the table HoldersKeys , but i don't know how to use contain to get the associated data using the previous code ?

can  any body help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `contain()` to your query.
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#loading-associations

```
<?php
$data = $this->CustodyKeys->HoldersKeys
            ->find(
                'all',
                ['conditions' => ['HoldersKeys.id' => $this->request->query['holders_keys_id']]]
            )
            ->contain('TableName');
```

Comment: Can you tell me , how to get data from CustodyKeys table too ?

Comment: Did you read the linked page from the manual? This is really basic stuff.